# Fiddler: Reconstructing files

Tags: fiddler, malware

I am recording sessions to malicious websites using Fiddler and want to be able to reconstruct malware dropped by the website onto a victim machine. Does Fiddler have this capability inbuilt? Suggestions for other tools that could achieve this with the Fiddler saz file are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Fiddler saves any files that are part of a successful download in the session. It can be viewed by right clicking on the request -> Inspect in new Window -> Response -> Textview.
Clicking on the dotted icon at the bottom right of this window saves the file in the IE temp folder. Alternatively, it can be saved to the desired location.